# Upload incoming form data received in an API request to Azure file storage

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-files

Suppose there's a web page that allows a user to upload a file. The file can be of any format/size.

There's a REST API based Flask Server running on an EC2 instance. In my case it's CentoOS 7+.

Once I receive the file in the HTTP request, I first need to download them on the CentOS server. After the file is downloaded, I would have to upload it to Azure File Storage.

I can do all of the above without any problem. 
However, is there a way where I can upload the file in the incoming request to Azure servers without downloadiing it on CentOS server.

Below is what I have done so far.

**app.py**

```
# Upserts uploads folder
base_path_uploads = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/uploads'

def create_directories(token):
    # Create a directory specific to the logged in client. All the call recording clips will be stored under it.
    path_to_tokenized_directories = (base_path_uploads + "/" + token)
    os.makedirs(path_to_tokenized_directories, exist_ok=True)
    return path_to_tokenized_directories



@app.route('/user/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # First, we shall fetch the token and see if a directory corresponding to its value exists
    try:

        ####This will be where I can receive one or more than one #files
        file = list(request.files['files'])
        token = request.form['token']

        # Path where user specific files are uploaded/deleted
        uploads_path = create_directories(token)

        # Save file on the current server
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + "/" + token, filename))

        files = file_share_crud_ops.azure_crud(token, "upload", uploads_path)
        api_response = jsonify({
            "status":
                "success",
            "message":
                "",
            "data": {
                "files": files
            }
        })
        api_response.status_code = 200
    except Exception as e:
        api_response = jsonify({
            "status":
                "failure",
            "message":
                "Unable to fetch your workspace data"
        })
api_response.status_code = 500
return api_response
```

**file_share_crud_ops**

```
def azure_crud(self, token, operation, user_directory_path):
        try:
            # Get the directory client
            user_workspace = share.get_directory_client(directory_path=token)

            # [START create_directory]
            try:
                user_workspace.create_directory()
            except:
                # Directory has already been created
                pass

            if "read" in operation:
                files_and_folders = list(share.list_directories_and_files(directory_name=token))
                for files_and_folder in files_and_folders:
                    files_and_folder['id'] = "1"
                    files_and_folder['type'] = "file"
                    files_and_folder['owner'] = "me"
                    files_and_folder['modified'] = ""
                    files_and_folder['opened'] = ""
                    files_and_folder['created'] = ""
                    files_and_folder['extention'] = ""
                    files_and_folder['location'] = ""
                    files_and_folder['offline'] = True
                return files_and_folders
            elif "upload" in operation:

                # Upload to Azure Files
                for filename in os.listdir(user_directory_path):

                    with open(filename, "rb") as source:
                        user_workspace.upload_file(file_name="visualization_-_aerial", data=source)



            # List files in the directory
            files_and_folders = list(share.list_directories_and_files(directory_name=token))


            return files_and_folders

        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError("Error while Creating or Fetching share content")
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written so far.

Comment: @GauravMantri Just did.

Comment: Thanks! I am not that well versed with Python but instead of writing the file to the disk, can't you read it as a stream and then upload that stream in file storage?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yeah. That's what should be the ideal case I was thinking of. Let me try it.